# Google Poly runtime takes up 1GB RAM on iPhone

Tags: unity-game-engine, arkit

I've noticed that the Google Poly Runtime is taking up about 1GB of memory on my iPhone when I build a simple ARKit app. This is without importing any models.

I'm using the Google Poly Unity toolkit and integrating it with the Unity ARKit Plugin. I'm running out of memory on my 2GB ram iPhone 7 very quickly.

Has anyone else seen this and is there any way to reduce this ?